# Possible to determine what plugins and versions are being used in a wordpress site?

Tags: web-application

I have been thinking about creating a Wordpress vulnerability scanner that would look for plugins being used by a Wordpress site and then search [osvdb](http://www.osvdb.org/) for known vulnerabilities.

I'm curious if there is an automated way to determine what plugins (and their version) a Wordpress site is using?  So far the only idea I have had is to go through each page and look for paths to the default:  `http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/whatever` path and then perhaps dig into js files to see if you can find a version number.

Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of existing software that does the same thing?

- [wpupdatescan](https://lolware.net/wpupdatescan.html)
- [wpscan](http://wpscan.org/)
- [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/releases/acunetix-wvs-v8-build-20130416/) (free version of commercial product)

Use a [method](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/how-to-detect-wp-plugins-used-on-a-site) to parse what plugins are used on a WordPress site, and then it's a simple compare to a vulnerability database.

Comment: No!  Thanks for the info.  I did notice that they say, `Added a test that identifies common WordPress plugins.` which is good, but I would prefer something that tries to identify all plugins (common or not).  Either way I'd rather not pay for the tool and I'd still enjoy writing my own tool that does it, so if you have any suggestions on how to identify the plugins I'd still love to hear it.

Comment: often done with brute force with a dictionary on the plug-in path. As for 'uncommon' plugins, you would need to know what you are looking for or have access to the webserver's file system.